# Cannot read property of undefined in react native flat list when using react testing library

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-context

I'm trying to create a simple snapshot test in react native using react-testing-library, but I can't figure out why I am getting "cannot read property 'lines' of undefined". The flatlist is rendering the data fine with no issues, but the test wont pass.

I've also tried destructuring out the summary.lines, but that didn't work either.

```
 ● Single Collection Screen Renders

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'lines' of undefined

      47 |         <FlatList
    > 48 |           data={summary.lines}
         |                     ^
      49 |           renderItem={renderCollectionOrderLines}
      50 |           keyExtractor={(_item, i) => i.toString()}
      51 |         />
```

Mock data.js:

```
export const useSingleOrdersMock = [
  {
    order_number: 'ABC/1234',
    date: '25/06/20',
    order_status: 'Processing',
    order_total: '£1000.25',
    delivery_address: {
      name: 'John Doe',
      short_name: 'Example Address',
      line_1: 'Example Street',
      line_2: 'United Kingdom',
      line_3: null,
      line_4: null,
      line_5: null,
      postcode: 'ABC 123',
    },
    invoice_address: {
      name: 'Steve Smith',
      short_name: 'Example Address',
      line_1: 'Example Street',
      line_2: 'United Kingdom',
      line_3: null,
      line_4: null,
      line_5: null,
      postcode: 'ABC 123',
    },
    summary: {
      subtotal: '£1100.25',
      delivery: 'Free',
      vat: '£100',
      lines: [
        {
          product_id: 123456,
          part_code: 'ABC1234',
          stock_code: '01234-5678',
          description: 'Combi Oven',
          quantity: 1,
          price_including_vat: '10.20',
          price_excluding_vat: '8.50',
          vat: '1.70',
        },
        {
          product_id: 678910,
          part_code: 'ABC1234',
          stock_code: '01234-5678',
          description: 'Combi Oven',
          quantity: 1,
          price_including_vat: '5.10',
          price_excluding_vat: '4.25',
          vat: '0.85',
        },
      ],
    },
  },
];

export const SingleCollectionScreenAccountContext = {
  selectedCollectionOrder: useSingleOrdersMock,
  setSelectedCollectionOrder: jest.fn(),
};
```

Test.js:

```
test('Single Collection Screen Renders', () => {
  let tree;
  act(() => {
    tree = renderer.create(
      <ScreenRenderer
        additionalAccountContext={SingleCollectionScreenAccountContext}>
        <SingleCollectionScreen />
      </ScreenRenderer>,
    );
  });
  expect(tree.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Component.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { ScrollView, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import Row from '../../components/Account/Row';
import { useAccountContext } from '../../providers/AccountProvider';

const SingleCollectionScreen = () => {
  const { selectedCollectionOrder } = useAccountContext();

  const {
    order_number,
    order_total,
    summary,
  } = selectedCollectionOrder;

  // const { lines } = summary
  
  const renderCollectionOrderLines = ({ item }) => {
    const {
      description,
      part_code,
      price_excluding_vat,
      quantity,
      stock_code,
    } = item;
    return (
      <SummaryLine
        itemName={description}
        catalogue={part_code}
        priceExVat={price_excluding_vat}
        quantity={quantity}
        stockCode={stock_code}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <ScreenContainer>
        <FlatList
          data={summary.lines}   <-- error occurring here
          renderItem={renderCollectionOrderLines}
          keyExtractor={(_item, i) => i.toString()}
        />
        <Row title="Subtotal" value={summary.subtotal} />
        <Row title="Delivery" value={summary.delivery} />
        <Row title="VAT" value={summary.vat} />
        <Row title="Total" value={orderTotal} highlight />
      </ScreenContainer>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default SingleCollectionScreen;
```

Comment: did you try adding a `?`. summary?.lines

Comment: and also confirm `summary?.lines` is not getting undefined by consoling `console.log(summary?.lines)`

Comment: Adding the question mark - summary?.lines, seems to have done the trick :)

Comment: ok i will post this as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in the initial rendering `summary.lines` is getting undefined because of asynchronous call.

To get rid of this issue add a `?` it will make a null check before executing

```
data={summary?.lines}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the summary data you are getting, is from an asynchronous call, thus at the initial point, its undefined.

In such scenario adding a null check helps in resolving such issues. Instead of `summary.lines`, try `summary?.lines`.